# Closing Iframe with Javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to close a Iframe and the below works for every browser except for IE7 an IE8. Any suggestions for IE?  The button acutally exists on the iframe itself.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="history.go(0)"
```

Comment: You forgot the code sample you are referring to.

Comment: He just failed as properly marking it as code.

Comment: What does "close an iframe" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what "close" means with regard to an `iframe` other than removing it, so:

You can remove an `iframe` from the document using `removeChild` on its parent node, e.g.:

```
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('theIframe');
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/abebi4)

There I'm using an `id` to find the `iframe` element in the parent window, but obviously you have lots of choices for how to find it. Ultimately it comes down to calling [**`removeChild`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1734834066).